# Java Class data type

Tags: java, class, instance-variables

```
Class Person {

  Person name;
  Person age;
  ..
}
```

In this usage , what does it mean **Person name** and **Person age**. Of course name and age data type is Person but I cannot understand the concept how will I use in my program. 
For example 
if I Person data type replaced by String name and int age , I will use in main method like:

```
Person p1 = new Person();
p1.name = "blabla";
p1.age = 30;
```

But how will we use the Person data type like that.
I have already searched on the Internet but I couldn't find anything about that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad (catastrophic) design decision.

Instead it should look like

```
class Person {
    String name;
    int age;
}
```

---

There are possibilities when using `Person` within `Person` would be justified. Look at the following examples.

```
class Person {
    Person manager; // Here, an employee could have another Person being its manager
}
```

---

```
class Person {
    Person partner; // Here, a person could be married and have another Person as partner
}
```

Comment: I have clearly understood.Thank you for your answering.

Comment: @redkit You're welcome. Feel free to upvote/accept the answer.

Comment: I have tried but before earn 15 reputation system said :)

Comment: @redkit You can always accept it by clicking on the arrow :)